# How can I connect the non-nan values with a line?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that I would like to plot in three subplots.

The index is a datetime so it is important that the xaxis line up across the subplots.

One column of my frame has data for only the first day of the year.  The remainder are nans.

Here is a sample.

```
           Cases    Coverage    Measles
2011-01-31  31.0    93.1    29.964546402502616
2011-02-28                  43.68275418275418
2011-03-31                  43.28153153153155
2011-04-30                  37.25000000000002
2011-05-31                  75.5229357798165
2011-06-30                  48.727064220183486
2011-07-31                  30.467948717948733
2011-08-31                  31.286418094278353
2011-09-30                 36.43205930461145
2011-10-31                  31.816645136232765
2011-11-30                  29.399802310147145
2011-12-31                  31.34712643678163
2012-01-31  8.0 93.3        0.80327868852459
```

I'd like to connect the non-nan `Cases` data with a dashed line, but since the values are nan for the remaining month, no line is drawn.

Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """date       Cases    Coverage    Measles
2011-01-31  31.0    93.1    29.964546402502616
2011-02-28  nan     nan     3.68275418275418
2011-03-31  nan     nan     43.28153153153155
2011-04-30  nan     nan     37.25000000000002
2011-05-31  nan     nan     75.5229357798165
2011-06-30  nan     nan     48.727064220183486
2011-07-31  nan     nan     30.467948717948733
2011-08-31  nan     nan     31.286418094278353
2011-09-30  nan     nan     36.43205930461145
2011-10-31  nan     nan     31.816645136232765
2011-11-30  nan     nan     29.399802310147145
2011-12-31  nan     nan     31.34712643678163
2012-01-31  8.0     93.     0.80327868852459
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])

# subset df with only columns that have nulls
dfna = df.loc[:, df.isnull().any()]

# plot the first df
ax = df.plot(marker='o')

# then fill in nulls with interpolate
# plot the result with dashed lines
dfna.interpolate('index').plot(ls='--', ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you